# Hint that return type is the same as the argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, type-hinting

I want a function to accept a Pydantic model and return its instance. And I want VS Code to understand the returned type and provide autocompletion. This doesn't work as intended:

```
T = pydantic.BaseModel

def get_request_data(RequestSchema: typing.Type[T]) -> T:
    try:
        return RequestSchema(**flask.request.get_json())
    except pydantic.ValidationError as exc:
        ...


class PagInputSchema(pydantic.BaseModel):
    dataset_id: int = pydantic.Field(alias='datasetId')
```

The model field names are not autocompleted:

[image]

Comment: As you indicate in your code example, you need to remove the single type constraint. If you want the type to be `pydantic.BaseModel`, then use just that, or you can also use a type alias.

Comment: @a_guest my point is not to make this code compile, I need to be able to make autocomplete work for the returned instance of a particular model passed to the function. In the screenshot I expect `dataset_id` to be suggested for autocomplete.

Comment: Your type checker can't handle invalid type annotations, so it doesn't know what you mean. Hence, it can't infer the type of `PagInputSchema`. Autocomplete will have the same problems.

Comment: `T = p.BaseModel` yields the same result. I've tried that. Sorry for probable confusion with the related SO answer.

Comment: Please update your code snippet such that it is valid. If you want to use a [type alias](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeAlias) you might need to annotate it as such.

Comment: Done. I don't want type alias. I want a way to hint that the return type is the same as the argument type (dynamic) so that for different function calls I would get different autocomplete suggestions.

Comment: I see, in that case you can use `T = TypeVar('T', bound=pydantic.BaseModel)`. That should work, at least from the type checking perspective.

Comment: Nope, same result: shows only attrs of BaseModel

Comment: Try checking your code with mypy. If mypy doesn't complain, then it's an issue with Visual Studio Code. I tried something similar with sample test classes and mypy didn't complain.

Comment: It's not about complaining/validating the code. I want autocomplete to work... Currently the code is valid. I'll try though.

Comment: That's more a visual studio question thatn a python question ...

Comment: @warvariuc The autocomplete tool works similarly to the type checker; if the type checker can't infer the type, the autocomplete tool won't do either. So crosschecking with mypy makes sense because, as I mentioned, if mypy passes, then it's definitely a Visual Studio question.

Answer (score 0):

This does it:

```
T = t.TypeVar("T")


def get_request_data(RequestSchema: t.Type[T]) -> T:
    ...
```

[image]